# Windows Azure VM Endpoints

Tags: windows, azure, port, endpoint

I am new to Windows Azure and have limited knowledge in networking. I have a VM running on windows azure that is configured to be having a virtual network. Thus, under Dashboard, the machine will have the following information:

```
Public virtual IP address (VIP): 168.62.210.xx
Internal IP Address: 10.1.1.4
```

I have a customized server running on that machine that will be listening on port 2641. Under Endpoints, I have:

```
Name   Protocol Public Port Private Port Load Balanced
Handle TCP      2641        2641         NO
```

I am assuming that there would be a NAT that basically routes incoming traffic from 168.62.210.xx:2641 to 10.1.1.4:2641 and vice versa (from 10.1.1.4 to 168.62.210.xx)?

Is there a way to verify whether that port is working or not?

On linux, the output of `nc -z 168.62.210.xx 2641; echo $?` is 1 (meaning port is not open).

If I set up the server, I am assuming that I would have to bind the server to 10.1.1.4 instead of 168.62.210.xx?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you opened the port (2641) on Windows Firewall on the VM?

Comment: Hmm, isn't that done automatically when we add an endpoint? I turned off the firewall and communication went through so firewall was blocking it.

Comment: No, adding the endpoint just allows traffic to flow (via the network).  Editing endpoints does not change the Windows Server firewall settings (makes no changes to the operating system).  With Virtual Machines (in an IaaS environment), you take on the responsibility to completely manage the operating system.  The Windows Azure management portal can help you configuring some networking options, but not the VM's operating system.

Comment: Are you sure your Linux machine can go to the Internet thru port 2641 ? Assuming your VM in Windows Azure is a Windows Server machine, not a Linux machine (it wouldn't be in a virtual network), have you tried to see if there is a process listening on port 2641 with a command like netstat -ano | find ":2641" ? For the firewall, add an inboud rule on port 2641. You can do that with Windows Firewall With Advanced security.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have configure the inbound and outbound security rules in network security group associated with the vm network interface.

Similar to the image listed below on the azure portal:
[image]

Another way to configure network rules in azure is calling Azure PowerShell SDK, you can make use of the code snippets below

```
# 0. set the target resource group name and target vm name
$ResourceGroupName = "ocoslab-eric" # set your own resource group
$VMName = "vm-eric-demo" # set your own vm name

# 1. get the vm information
$VM = Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $VMName

# 2. get the network interface information
$NICID = $VM.NetworkInterfaceIDs[0]
$NICName = ([regex]"/.*/(.*?)$").Match($NICID).Groups[1].Value
$NICResourceGroupName = ([regex]"/resourceGroups/(.*?)/").Match($NICID).Groups[1].Value
$NIC = Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface -Name $NICName -ResourceGroupName $NICResourceGroupName

# 3. get or create the associated security network group
If ($NIC.NetworkSecurityGroup -eq $null) {
    $NSG = New-AzureRmNetworkSecurityGroup -Name 'custom-nsg' -Location $VM.Location -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName
    $NIC.NetworkSecurityGroup = $NSG
} Else {
    $NSGId = $NIC.NetworkSecurityGroup.Id
    $NSGName = ([regex]"/.*/(.*?)$").Match($NSGId).Groups[1].Value
    $NSGResourcGroup = ([regex]"/resourceGroups/(.*?)/").Match($NSGId).Groups[1].Value
    $NSG = Get-AzureRmNetworkSecurityGroup -Name $NSGName -ResourceGroupName $NSGResourcGroup
    $NIC.NetworkSecurityGroup = $NSG
}

# 4. create security rule to allow the port and associate with the security network group
# Parameter explanation:
#   a.  -Name                       Specifies the name of a network security rule configuration
#   b.  -Access                     Specifies whether network traffic is allowed or denied. psdx_paramvalues Allow and Deny.
#   c.  -Protocol                   Specifies the network protocol that a rule configuration applies to. 
#                                   - Tcp
#                                   - Udp
#                                   - Wildcard character (*) to match both 
#   d.  -Direction                  Specifies whether a rule is evaluated on incoming or outgoing traffic. psdx_paramvalues Inbound and Outbound.
#   e.  -SourceAddressPrefix        Specifies a source address prefix. psdx_paramvalues
#                                   - A CIDR
#                                   - A source IP range
#                                   - A wildcard character (*) to match any IP address.
#   f.  -SourcePortRange            Specifies a source port or range. This value is expressed as an integer, as a range between 0 and 65535, or as a wildcard character (*) to match any source port.
#   g.  -DestinationAddressPrefix   Specifies a destination address prefix. psdx_paramvalues
#                                   - A Classless Interdomain Routing (CIDR) address
#                                   - A destination IP address range
#                                   - A wildcard character (*) to match any IP address  
#   h.  -DestinationPortRange       Specifies a destination port or range. psdx_paramvalues
#                                   - An integer
#                                   - A range of integers between 0 and 65535
#                                   - A wildcard character (*) to match any port
#   i.  -Priority                   Specifies the priority of a rule configuration. psdx_paramvalues An integer between 100 and 4096. The priority number must be unique for each rule in the collection. The lower the priority number, the higher the priority of the rule.

Add-AzureRmNetworkSecurityRuleConfig  -NetworkSecurityGroup $NSG `
                -Name 'custom_rule_name' `
                -Access Allow `
                -Protocol Tcp `
                -Direction Inbound `
                -SourceAddressPrefix Internet `
                -SourcePortRange * `
                -DestinationAddressPrefix * `
                -DestinationPortRange 3389 `
                -Priority 100 | Out-Null

# 5 finally, set the NetworkSecurityGroup and NetworkInterface state
Set-AzureRmNetworkSecurityGroup -NetworkSecurityGroup $NSG | Out-Null
Set-AzureRmNetworkInterface -NetworkInterface $NIC | Out-Null

Write-Host "Done"
```

And, for the complete code sample downloadable bits, please visit the [How to manage port for Azure Virtual Machine by PowerShell](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/How-to-manage-port-for-8c71fed6)